# Вопрос? В чём причина?

Tags: java

/*При вводе n-го количества символов при условии, что первый введённый символ находится в диапазоне от 1 до 5 программа работает не корректно. */

```
public class Help2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char choice, ignore;

        do {
            System.out.println("Справка: ");
            System.out.println("1. if");
            System.out.println("2. switch");
            System.out.println("3. for");
            System.out.println("4. while");
            System.out.println("5. do-while\n");
            System.out.print("Выберите: ");

            choice = (char) System.in.read();

            do {
                ignore = (char) System.in.read();
            } while(ignore != '\n');
        } while(choice < '1' | choice > '5');
        System.out.println("\n");

        switch(choice) {
            case '1':
                System.out.println("Оператор if:\n");
                System.out.println("if(условие) оператор;");
                System.out.println("else оператор;");
                break;
            case '2':
                System.out.println("Оператор switch:\n");
                System.out.println("switch(выражение) {");
                System.out.println("case константа:");
                System.out.println("Последовательность операторов");
                System.out.println("break");
                System.out.println(" // ...");
                System.out.println("}");
                break;
            case '3':
                System.out.println("Оператор for:\n");
                System.out.println("for(инициализация; условие; интерация)");
                System.out.println("оператор;");
                break;
            case '4':
                System.out.println("Оператор while:\n");
                System.out.println("while(условие) оператор;");
                break;
            case '5':
                System.out.println("Операто do-while:\n");
                System.out.println("do {");
                System.out.println("оператор;");
                System.out.println("} while(условие);");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: например: 23 или 456

Comment: что вы ожидаете должно происходить при вводе таких чисел и что происходит на самом деле?

Comment: повторный запрос на ввод, а не завершение

Comment: Посмотрите на строчку  ignore = (char) System.in.read();  - приведение типов и тип данных не о чем не говорит?

Comment: под последовательностью символов я так же подразумеваю не только символы алфавита, но и числа. Если вести, допустим, символ от 1 до 5 получаем нужный результат. Если символы в любой последовательности и количестве не зависимо от регистра, а так же числа, при условии что ввод данной последовательности будет начинаться не от 1 до 5. Если ввод начинается с 1 или/до 5 происходит завершение, а не повторное приглашение на ввод.

Comment: Формулируйте, пожалуйста, вопросы так, чтобы из заголовка была видна суть вопроса, а в самом вопросе четко обозначьте, что вы хотите получить, и что получается вместо этого. Убирайте из кода дедатили, не относящиеся к вашей проблеме.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса: "Вопрос? В чем причина?" не говорит ни о чем, а из текста вопроса совершенно непонятно, что такое "некорректно", о котором вы говорите. Как программа должна, по вашему мнению, вести себя, и как она ведет себя фактически -- можно понять, только прочитав все комментарии. Сам текст программы загроможден строками вывода, которые не имеют никаого отношения к сути вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подумайте сами внимательно, представьте, что это не Java, а вы выполняете свою программу. Посмотрите вот на этот фрагмент вашего кода:

```
do {
    // тут что-то пишем  
    // Потом вводим, напр. "123\n"
    choice = (char) System.in.read();  // ввели choice = '1'.  

    do {
        ignore = (char) System.in.read(); // Читаем все остальное - '2', '3', '\n'
                                              // * choice не меняется, '1'    
    } while(ignore != '\n');              // Пока не встретили '\n'. 
                                              // * choice по-прежнему == '1'
} while(choice < '1' | choice > '5');     // choice == '1', выходим из цикла
                                              // * Вышли из цикла, choise == '1'
// Выводим описание операторов, choise == '1', значит, оператор if...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я наконец-то понял. Всем хорошего дня.